# Java constructors confusion?

Tags: java, object-oriented, constructors, static

```
public class example 
{
    private String one;
    private String two;
    public example(String one, String two)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(returning());
    }

    public static example returning()
    {
        return new example("yes", "no");
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return one + " SPACESPACESPACE " + two;
    }
}

run:
yes SPACESPACESPACE no
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I was trying to learn how constructors work, and I wrote some code that had a `toString` method. I called `System.out.print` on the `returning()` function, and it printed "yes SPACESPACESPACE no" which is only found in the `toString` method. However, I never had an object for the `toString` method to act on (namely `objectCreatedFromClass.toString()`), so I never actually used the `toString` method.

Can someone explain to me why this happened? Why was I allowed to return a new object, namely `return new example("yes", "no")` when my class
is a static method?

Comment: How do you think `System.out.println` turns objects into strings that it can print out?

Comment: But when you System.out.println an object, wouldn't it give you the getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()) instead? But somehow I get a toString of that? Which is interestingly odd?

Comment: I believe you just described the default implementation of `Object.toString()`.

Comment: @gordonsung have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet You are right. I apologize.

Comment: Thank you  @Ixrec and @ Snowman  for your answers and reply. I am grateful!

Comment: @gordonsung I rewrote the text of your question to try to make it a bit more clear what you're asking. Feel free to reject or roll back the edit if you think it conflicts with your original intentions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`println` follows convention and calls your object's `toString()` when it needs to, in order to obtain a string from some class it doesn't know about.

The default `Object.toString()` implementation gives you `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`, but you've overridden it with your own version. You're seeing the results of that version.

Answer (score 3):

> Why was I allowed to return a new object, namely `return new example("yes", "no")` when my class is a static method?

Constructors can be called by anything that knows about them (via `import foo.bar.MyClass;` or part of the same file), and has access to them (`public` or same class). Since `returning()` is part of your `example` class, it can call its constructors.

Note that if static methods could *not* call constructors, we'd be in trouble. The first method that runs in a Java program is `main()`, which is static. If `main()` could not call any constructors, we could never construct *any* objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your returning method. And create and example object in main method:
 example n1=new example("yes","no");
 System.out.println(n1);

It suppose to work! So if you will not write a method toString here your system will print out only address where your object store. But if you do a method it will print your String.

It will be better if you will write your contractor and main method in different classes, it will make your code clear :):)